# Unwanted extra space with custom biblatex title style using polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia

I'm redefining the "title" bibmacro in order to include the original title of the work. As seen here, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.[image: Failure!]In case it isn't obvious, there's a lot of bonus space after the bracket in the second entry.

Here's my MWE that produced this image:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=0.2in]{standalone}

\RequireXeTeX
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{czech,spanish}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=standard]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \printtext[title]{%
    \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
    \iffieldundef{subtitle}%
      {}%
      {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}\printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
    \iffieldundef{origtitle}%
      {}%
      {\setunit{\addspace}\printtext[brackets]{\printfield{origtitle}}}}%
  \newunit}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Grusa,
  Author = {Jiří Gruša},
  Location = {New York},
  Origlanguage = {czech},
  Origtitle = {\textczech{Dotazník, aneb modlitba za jedno město a přítele}},
  Publisher = {Farrar Straus Giroux},
  Title = {The Questionnaire, or Prayer for a Town and a Friend},
  Translator = {Peter Kussi},
  Year = {1982}}

@book{Cortazar:Fires,
  Author = {Julio Cortázar},
  Location = {New York},
  Origlanguage = {spanish},
  Origtitle = {\textspanish{Todos los fuegos el fuego}},
  Publisher = {Pantheon Books},
  Title = {All Fires the Fire and Other Stories},
  Translator = {Suzanne Jill Levine},
  Year = {1973}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

Based on what I have here, I have no idea where the bonus space is coming from. I freely admit that I don't have any idea if this the best way to do what I want to do, so if there's a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: The two entries are exactly parallel, but the extra space shows up only in the Czech translation.  And, looking at the width of the gap, multiple non-consecutive spaces are involved.  My guess is that it is the fault of (unintended) spaces in the definition of `\textczech` loaded by `polyglossia`.  There are others more capable of fixing this than I, but that's where I'd look.

Comment: it is a bug in gloss-czech, with luatex there is one spurious space in the code, with xelatex quite a number. A simple xxx\textczech{abc}yyy demonstrates it. Open an issue at the polyglossia repo.

Comment: This is a bug (well, a few forgotten `%`s) in `polyglossia`'s Czech language module, I reported it at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected by barbara beeton and also mentioned by Ulrike Fischer, the problem comes from a few spurious spaces due to missing `%`s in `polyglossia`'s Czech language module. The problem can be reproduced without `biblatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{czech,spanish}

\begin{document}
A\textczech{B}C

A\textspanish{B}C
\end{document}
```

[image: A BC//ABC]

Issues like this should be reported to the `polyglossia` maintainers. They usually take care of these things quite swiftly. I reported the issue in https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/423 (the issue was fixed shortly after reporting and should be in the next `polyglossia` release, in case it is urgent one can probably get the `.ldf` files from https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/commit/e088311159a5db2403d2ed672eaf42c0a74a24fd and use them as drop-in replacements for the faulty files).

As a quick work-around you can set the `polyglossia-czech` option `vlna` to `false`. You quite probably don't want to do that in a document with significant text in Czech, but may get away with it if you only have short passages of Czech.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[vlna=false]{czech}
\setotherlanguage{spanish}

\begin{document}
A\textczech{B}C

A\textspanish{B}C
\end{document}
```

[image: ABC//ABC]

---

Just so this answer contains something interesting, here is a solution that automatically adds `\text<language>` around `origtitle` according to the value of `origlanguage` (cf. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/594).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[vlna=false]{czech}% TEMPORARY workaround
% for https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/423
\setotherlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origtitle:origlang:polyglossia}{%
  \iflistundef{origlanguage}
    {#1}
    {\ifcsundef{text\thefirstlistitem{origlanguage}}
       {\PackageWarning{biblatex}{%
          No language switching for
          \thefirstlistitem{origlanguage}}%
        #1}
       {\csuse{text\thefirstlistitem{origlanguage}}{#1}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \printtext[title]{%
    \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
    \iffieldundef{subtitle}%
      {}%
      {\setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
    \iffieldundef{origtitle}%
      {}%
      {\setunit{\addspace}%
       \printtext[brackets]{\printfield[origtitle:origlang:polyglossia]{origtitle}}}}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Grusa,
  Author       = {Jiří Gruša},
  Location     = {New York},
  Origlanguage = {czech},
  Origtitle    = {Dotazník, aneb modlitba za jedno město a přítele},
  Publisher    = {Farrar Straus Giroux},
  Title        = {The Questionnaire, or Prayer for a Town and a Friend},
  Translator   = {Peter Kussi},
  Year         = {1982},
}
@book{Cortazar:Fires,
  Author       = {Julio Cortázar},
  Location     = {New York},
  Origlanguage = {spanish},
  Origtitle    = {Todos los fuegos el fuego},
  Publisher    = {Pantheon Books},
  Title        = {All Fires the Fire and Other Stories},
  Translator   = {Suzanne Jill Levine},
  Year         = {1973},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] Julio Cortázar. All Fires the Fire and Other Stories [Todos los fuegos el fuego]. Trans. from the Spanish by Suzanne Jill Levine. New York: Pantheon Books, 1973.//[2] Jiří Gruša. The Questionnaire, or Prayer for a Town and a Friend [Dotazník, aneb modlitba za jedno město a přítele]. Trans. from the Czech by Peter Kussi. New York: Farrar Straus Giroux, 1982.]

Comment: Just as an addition: The spurious space with luatex is caused by the luavlna package. See https://github.com/michal-h21/luavlna/issues/5 (the xelatex issues are fixed for the next polyglossia version)

Comment: Wow. Great answer, and great bonus answer as well. Thanks!